# How to calculate per site meta reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, stack-exchange, data-explorer, per-site-meta

The displayed reputation on per site meta is the same as on the respective parent site. However, out of curiosity, I'd like to see the actual reputation users would have on a meta if it was counted independently. I toyed around with the data explorer (and fruitlessly used its search), but all the extras like rep-cap, answer-accepts and bonuses were too much for my crappy SQL and I don't think there is much point in re-implementing the rep-computation algorithm since it's already there.

So, is there a way to show the theoretical meta-rep of users?

Comment: This would probably require two separate accounts (with the current implementation), as well as a few well-crafted queries to filter the history of your half-profile into the "new" meta one. As the original meta site (this one) is the only one implemented through a separate account, I'm afraid this might not be the direction the developers are currently aiming for.

Comment: You can't start bounties on per-site Metas... So no need to worry about that one.

Comment: @animuson: Good point. I was trying to approximate the reputation by comparing it to a reference, hence I tried some queries on mains, which do have bounties.

Answer (score 12):

I have some queries that do an approximation of reputation and work also on meta sites (I used meta.stackoverflow.com as a target site here):

- [Top users by reputation with rep cap and member for days](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/204782/top-users-by-reputation-with-rep-cap-and-member-for-days)
- [Robert Harvey's user reputation history](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/203302/user-reputation-history?uid=102937#graph)
- [Top users rep per x weeks](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/196452/top-users-rep-per-x-weeks)

Remember that all data is updated weekly on Sunday 03:00 UTC. Not all data is available in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com), for example voting is anonymous.

Comment: My on MSO is 1,798 :D Thanks!

Comment: Now my rep on MSO is 2,282. Eh, would be good if child metas had rep....

Comment: My MSO rep is 5,210 :). Thanks for the query.