# Include meta reputation in the Users table for meta sites

Tags: feature-request, reputation, data-explorer, per-site-meta

The table Users returns the same number as reputation if a query is run [on the meta site](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1425733/users-with-top-reputation) and [on the main site](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1425733/users-with-top-reputation). Maybe it would make more sense to user "meta reputation" from meta if the query is run on meta.

Let me clarify what I mean by "meta reputation": I mean reputation calculated from posts on a per-site meta in the same way it is calculated from the posts on the main site. I know that such value isn't displayed anywhere. But I suppose that Stack Exchange software calculates it somewhere (without showing it), for example, I'd expect that this is basis for [awarding Mortarboard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard), [Epic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/42/epic) and [Legendary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary) badges on per-site metas. EDIT: Some comments pointed out that on metas these might be actually awarded badges based on upvotes/scores rather than gained reputation.<sup>1</sup>

I suppose that sometimes it might be interesting to see "meta reputation" for users. (Of course, I am aware that from the stuff available in SEDE, I can get total score on non-CW answers, which seems like a reasonable approximation of reputation.) On the other hand, I will freely admit that I have no idea how difficult would adding this information into SEDE be.

<sup>1</sup>Related posts: [Should I really have been awarded mortarboard on a Per-site meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78603), [How can I see my meta reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266527) (Meta Stack Overflow), [“Mortarboard” continues to be awarded on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251249) (Meta Stack Overflow). Maybe also: [How to calculate per site meta reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172242) (Thanks for pointing out these posts in the comments.)

Comment: Nice catch on those badges

Comment: Related: [How to calculate per site meta reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172242/348196)

Comment: See also [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266528/8967612) on Meta.SO which suggests that the value might not actually be _stored_ anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

This feature request makes sense, but until that, you can use one of the various queries to compute (an approximation) yourself. Using [one of mine](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1170724/reputation-graph#graph), I was able to generate this graph of your reputation on Mathematics Meta.

[image]

Coincidentally, your Math.Meta virtual reputation is almost equal to your Math reputation!

Note that many similar queries use the old reputation system which (up to [November 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers)) only gave +5 reputation for question upvotes. They do show the correct (virtual) reputation in, say, 2018, but the reputation system changes were applied retroactively. The newer queries, including the one I linked to, approximate the 'official' graphs on your [site profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) and [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation), and the way Mortarboard and similar badges are awarded.

Comment: For sale of completeness may I remind you of our 'meta Flair' discussion, and the [query to calculate badge count on all Meta sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.space/query/1083622/badge-count-across-the-network-to-match-what-would-be-your-flair-but-for-meta-si); while not mentioned in the question I feel that the badge count is part of the reputation obtained on [tag:per-site-meta]. --- I'll leave it up to you if this would improve your answer, or you could delete this comment if it's not helpful.

Comment: Doesn't that blog post from '19 mention that the question rep bump was made retroactive, so that all upvotes on questions made before the change were also made to be worth +10 instead of +5? Why would you need the old calculation up until Nov. '19?

Comment: @zcoop98 you're right, the last paragraph was confusing. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @Rob it's not what the OP is after, but it's good to have [it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341045/295232) linked here.